# Anchor tag around table is not clickable in IE 6, 7 & 8

Tags: xhtml, html-table, anchor

The problem: when surrounding a table with an anchor tag, the table and everything within is not clickable in IE 6, 7 & 8.  How do I solve this issue assuming I can't replace the table with divs?

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://www.google.com">
  <table height="35">
    <tr>
      <td>I'm a link in a table, bet you can'tclick me!</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it a big table with lots of elements?

Comment: FWIW wrapping a link around any block element, whether a `table` or a `div`, is just as invalid.

Comment: Interesting, your sample code works as you expect in Google Chrome and Firefox, but not IE...

Comment: I did try the example.  I just wanted to get a feel for the scope of the HTML he would be generating.  For example, Asaph's solution--while perfectly valid--may be less than optimal if he has a table with 100's of cells.  If you really just want any click on the whole table to go to some URL, then JS or another method may make sense.

Comment: @bobince - HTML5 does support flow content (aka block elements) inside anchor tags, but it looks like IE9 still doesn't support it tables :(  But it works well with divs and many other block elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a JavaScript onclick event handler on the table to do the same thing as the link.

*Edit:* Removed initial suggestion since it behaved badly in other browsers.

Answer (score 7):

You can't have a table inside an anchor tag, as the table is a block tag and the anchor is an inline tag. Block tags don't go inside inline tags, so the code is invalid. Replacing the table with div elements doesn't work either, as they also are block elements.

The standards specifies how valid code should work, but not how invalid code should work. Different browsers have different methods of making the best of the situation. One alternative for the browser in this case is to move the anchor inside the table, another alternative is to move the table out of the anchor. Either method will give the desired result in some situations but not others.

The only way to reliably put a block element inside an anchor, is to use an element that is an inlinde element by default, and use CSS to turn both elements into block elements:

```
<a href="http://www.guffa.com" style="display:block;">
  <span style="display:block;">Eat me</span>
</a>
```

The code is valid as both elements are inline elements by default, and it works after the style is applied as a block element can be inside another block element.

Comment: Obviously you can have a table inside an anchor tag. Whether or not it conforms to the specification is a different question.

Comment: @Dan Finch: Obviously you can write absolutely anything, and the browsers will still try to display it in some way. If you put a table in an anchor tag, some browsers in some modes will either automatically end the anchor tag, or move the table outside the anchor tag. Both will still be in the page, but it doesn't work as you expected it to.

Comment: Just to update those who stumble upon this answer - HTML5 now supports block level elements (more specifically flow elements) inside anchor tags.  This includes elements like tables and divs, but not subsequent anchor tags.  Though html5 support is still hit or miss in some cases in modern browsers at this point in time.

Answer (score 3):

Why not do this?

```
<table height="35">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://www.google.com">I'm a link in a table, bet you can click me!</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 this is the right thing (valid and cross-browser compatible), long-winded though it may be for a very large number of cells.

Comment: The example I provided was a very simplified version of my problem.  In the table I was actually trying to work with there are 8-10 cells depending on content.  That would make for a lot of extra markup I don't want to have.

Comment: This solution technically isn't equivalent because the entire box is not clickable.  That being said, you could expand the size of the anchors to fill the box if your layout does NOT use cellspacing/padding/margins.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution:

```
<a href='#' onclick="location='http://www.google.com'" >
  <table height="35">
    <tr>
      <td>I'm a link in a table, bet you can'tclick me!</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I too got this problem today and searched for a fix, but couldn't find a working solution for it. So I just came up with this small jquery solution. You can modify it as you want. Hope this will give an idea to those of you struggling with this IE7 issue.

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('a').each(function(){
         if($(this).children().length != 0){
             $(this).click(function(){
               var url = $(this).attr('href');
               window.location = url;
             });
          }
       });
   });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a solution for this, it's not perfect but it works:

### Simplified CSS:

```
a{ display:inline-block; position:relative; }
a:after{ content:''; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:url('x'); }
```

### Simplified HTML:

```
<a href='http://dropthebit.com' target='_blank'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2</td>
        <td>cell 3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</a>
```

[**Test page**](http://jsfiddle.net/hekW9/1/)

---

Another way is using JavaScript event delegation on all links on IE9 like below:

```
if( !('placeholder' in document.createElement('input')) ) // IE9 and below
    $(document).on('click.ie', 'a', function(){ // bind a delegated event
        window.location = $(this).prop('href');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are crazy enough to support IE 7, 8 and 9 at all, you should know that you cannot have a TABLE inside an A tag in these dummy browsers.

This is true even in the case where you make the anchor display like a block element. You can however place a div inside an anchor tag, which for me is even more bizarre.

There are NO other solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add href attribute  directly to table insted of wrapping table in anchor tag.

```
<table height="35" href="http://www.google.com" id="link">
    <tr>
      <td>I'm a link in a table, bet you can'tclick me!</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

use on click on table for navigating to corrosponding url

```
$('#link').click(function () {
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this:

```
<a href="domain.com/page.htm">
<table><tr><td>Hello World!</td><td><img src="image.jpg"></td></tr></table>
</a>
```

First, you have to make an universal code that's work in all browsers without JavaScript like:

```
<table class="fixlink">
<tr><td>
<a href="domain.com/page.htm">Hello World!</a>
</td><td>
<a href="domain.com/page.htm"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now it works when you click items inside the table but no the entire table(but a little works!). Then, you have to apply a final fix JavaScript code in case browser has enable JS using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) like this:

```
$('.fixlink').each(function() {
    var a = $(this);
    var b = a.find('a').eq(0)
    var c = b.attr('href');
    var d = b.attr('target');
    if(typeof d === 'undefined'){d='_self'};
    a.click(function(){
        window.open(c, d);
        });
    a.css({'cursor':'pointer'});
    a.find('a').contents().unwrap();
    });// fixlink
```

And now it entirely works, in case browser doesn't have enable JS, works clicking inside