# Entire Button Clickable

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

I don't know much about HTML, basically only what I've taught myself (so if you answer please don't speak in developer language hehe).
I need the entire below styled button to be clickable, not just the text. I've been researching all over google but can't work it out.
Also the corners only appear rounded in some browsers and square in others, is there a way to get it to appear rounded in most if not all browsers?

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table style="background-color: #434242; border: 4px solid #ffffff; border-radius: 30px; -moz-border radius: 30px -webkit-border-radius: 30px;" border="0" width="20%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<td style="color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: -.20px; line-height: 100%; padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;" align="center" valign="middle"><a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.myurl.com">MY SITE</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
```

Comment: Just a tip: put your styling elements in a seperate css-file. Putting it in your html file is not the correct way to do it.

Comment: Most of the product content on our site uploads from our company accounting and database package, and the rest comes from the CMS. The CSS are locked and owned by a third party company who charge like a wounded bull for any changes to the CSS.... SO I have to work around it by doing everything in HTML myself :(

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using `onClick` you could just do this:

Add `cursor:pointer` to the `td` which turns the cursor into the hand pointer and add `onClick="window.location = http://www.stackoverflow.com;"` which is JavaScript that when the item is clicked, it sends the user to `http://www.stackoverflow.com`

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>

      <table style="background-color: #434242; border: 4px solid #ffffff; border-radius: 30px; -moz-border radius: 30px -webkit-border-radius: 30px;" border="0" width="20%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <td style="color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: -.20px; line-height: 100%; padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px; cursor:pointer;" align="center" valign="middle" onClick="window.location = http://www.stackoverflow.com;">MY SITE
        </td>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

OR

Wrap the link (`<a>`) around the inner `table`  *** Will not work on older browsers ***:

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.myurl.com">
        <table style="background-color: #434242; border: 4px solid #ffffff; border-radius: 30px; -moz-border radius: 30px -webkit-border-radius: 30px;" border="0" width="20%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <td style="color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: -.20px; line-height: 100%; padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;" align="center" valign="middle">MY SITE</td>
        </table>
      </a>
     </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Note that this will cause issues in older browsers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457439/anchor-tag-around-table-is-not-clickable-in-ie-6-7-8

Comment: @nullability Trying to keep it simple for a new learner.  However that is correct.

Comment: that's not really a good practice. The area outside the TD/Table becomes clickable too

Comment: @HarshulPandav correct, but it is a simple solution for a beginner, who could later learn to change the pointer and use jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: Updated a JavaScript version.

Answer (score 0):

By simply adding the following rule to your CSS

```
a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aka8uc0f/1/

Comment: Covers most but not all of the button.  I like this attempt however.

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately I don't have access to our CSS as they're owned by a company who charge trillions of dollars to make any changes to them ..

Comment: that's fine.. you can add this to the 'style' attribute of the <a> tag

Answer (score 0):

Do you specifically need it to be in a table tag?  If not, it would be easier just to style the link itself, like this:

```
<a style="padding: 6px 35px; background-color: #434242; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: -.2px; text-decoration: none; font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif; border-radius: 20px; font-size: 12px;" href="http://myurl.com">My Site</a>
```

Alternately, you can add what's called a class to the link and define the class in the CSS of your site.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.mysite-button {padding: 6px 35px; 
background-color: #434242; 
color: #fff; 
text-transform: uppercase; 
letter-spacing: -.2px; 
text-decoration: none; 
font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif; 
border-radius: 20px; 
font-size: 12px;}
</style>
</head>


<body>


<a class="mysite-button" href="http://myurl.com">My Site</a>
</body>
```

See link here to view all of these in action: http://jsfiddle.net/nk365o77/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are after a button, you should use the appropriate tag.

```
<button>
     Submit
</button>
```

And then style your html element in a separate css file. For example

```
button {
background-color: #ccc;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius:6px;
color: #fff;
font-family: 'Oswald';
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
border:none;
}
```

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bkoe1qg/), below your button.

Answer (score 0):

About the rounded corners. You forgot the ";" sign.

Wrong:

```
border-radius: 30px; -moz-border radius: 30px -webkit-border-radius: 30px;"
```

Correct:

```
border-radius: 30px; -moz-border radius: 30px; -webkit-border-radius: 30px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Going the beginner route, eh?

HTML is meant to be semantic, so perhaps a table isn't the best option for this. You should also watch the order in which you put your code. Be weary of inline styles (putting the style directly in the html). This makes for all sorts of havoc as you advance, and it's tedious, too! Icky.

I hope this is the solution you're looking for. Do you know how to link a css file?

http://jsfiddle.net/gw3n1vmp/1/  <- see how it works

```
<style>
table {
    background: #434242;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 20%;
    cellspacing:0;
    cellpadding:0;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2px;
}

td {
    text-align: center;
    display:block;
}

.table a {
    padding: 8px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
}
</style>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.myurl.com" title="my site">MY SITE</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: On that link, you can try manipulating the css (top-right) to change the colours, text, etc.

Comment: The CSS are locked and owned by our web provider who charge ridiculous horrific observed insane amounts of money to make any changes to it..

Comment: Sure will do, just need to work out how to do that. There isn't any button here to click called "accept answer".

Answer (score 0):

Don't put padding in the `<button>` tag. Put the same padding size in `<a>` tag and whole button will be clickable, like this:

```
a {
    display: block;
    padding: 40px 70px;
}
```